# Using HTML template inside Vaadin application

Tags: java, html, templates, vaadin, vaadin7

I have one situation where I need to use external Email HTML template, compile and populate it with data, attach with Email as body and send it. I have used `CustomLayout` class for using custom html template but not sure if I can use something similar for above case. **Is it possible to generate String HTML representation of Vaadin components (such as rendered `CustomLayout`)** ?

Comment: what components are we talking here?  full blown things like buttons and tables or just a few labels?  well in any case, i'd rather got with thymeleaf or whatever template library is your favourite.  you will have a really tough time to make this happen.  yet you can reuse the CSS from your theme to make the generated code _look_ like your UI.

Comment: @cfrick Yes we are looking a full blown like entire table which may have labels etc. thymeleaf seems nice but I do not have clear picture how to implement it with vaadin server side code. can you please add few more points ? thanks

Comment: another alternative would be to place html template inside property file and use them with Message Formatter to add values at placeholder. will it be nice one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to get the generated HTML from client side and transfer it to the server by creating your own client-side extension or by using this example: [Dumping the Screen](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book/#advanced.jsapi.screendump).

But if you want to create templates for you emails I suggest to use an approach where you use a template library that generates the html for your email.

Comment: would be much helpful if you could suggest any template library and example which supports vaadin.

Comment: This problem is not related to Vaadin so any templating library works.

Comment: agreed. I can see gagawa and freemarker etc which can help to generate them. :) now its clear to me. I was heading to wrong direction. thank you